# Taking In-App purchases to mimic my iPhone app on Android

Tags: android, iphone

I have an iPhone application which is a reporting application, by this I mean, a user searches for a postcode, and gets information for free on that postcode. Then for a cost (about £1-£3) they can purchase a complete report.

I purchase the report data legitimately per request, and put a markup on the price and deliver it through the iPhone.

I have been pulling my hair out with my android application as I can't find an answer on how to do the same for Google. Paypal has an API, but I am unsure if I will get approval in the market.

I don't care who takes their cut, be it Google through checkout (cant find anyway to implement) or PayPal, but my business model works by letting the user search for free to obtain basic data, and upsells them useful data.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this on Android yet. Read the Market agreement, it forbids you from selling anything directly from within the app. Hopefully they'll come with an IAP-like API soon.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that, can you think of anyway I can monitise my application, I really want to get onto the android market, but cant think of a way. I have a successful app on iphone but I need to expand the user base.

Comment: Can someone please confirm that I CANNOT use this and get onto the market place? https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep if so, why have paypal produced it? and call it in-app?

Comment: You really need to speak to qualified legal counsel. StackOverflow is for programming Q&A, not how to interpret the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to do so :-)
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html